# Uniform Convergence of Operators implies convergence of their norms

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

This may be a silly question, but I was asked to prove the following statement:

Let $T_n\to T$ uniformly (here the $T_n$ are bounded linear operators from Banach space $X$ to Banach Space $Y$), by this we mean:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \|T_n - T\|_{op} = 0
$$ 
The question asks me to prove that $\|T_n\| \to \|T\|$. But this seems like a one line proof. Namely, the reverse triangle inequality tells us:

$$
|\|T_n\| - \|T\|| \leq \|T_n - T\| 
$$
And taking limits (squeeze theorem etc.) on both sides proves the result. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything!

Comment: Thanks, the question seemed a little silly so I wanted to make sure I was doing things right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not missing anything. That's the standard way of proving that $T_n\to T$ implies $\|T_n\|\to\|T\|$.